# How to get the total number of tracks on jPlayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I'm currently adding and deleting tracks from my playlist dynamically with playlist.add() and playlist.remove(). Once there are no more tracks left in the playlist, I want to hide the player div container, effectively hiding the player itself. So, everytime I remove a track, I want to check for the total number of tracks currently in the playlist. Once it reaches 0, I should be able to hide the container.

Some codes (though I feel it is not necessary):

Setting the playlist:

```
    var maPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
                jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
                cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
            }, [], {
                swfPath: "js",
                supplied: "oga, mp3",
                wmode: "window",
                smoothPlayBar: true,
                keyEnabled: true
            });
```

Adding to playlist:

```
maPlaylist.add({
title: trackTitle,
mp3: "path/" + track.uid + "/" + track.filename,
    oga: "path/" + track.uid + "/" + track.filename
});
```

Removing from playlist:

```
if( maPlaylist.remove(arrayPos) )
    alert("Track removed successfully!");
else
    alert("Failed to remove track from the playlist!");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was actually stupidly simple, staring me in the face all along.

The playlist is an array (of course! durr!).  So, it was just a matter of getting the length of the array. Like so:

```
    console.log(maPlaylist.playlist.length);
```

I hope this helps someone in the future.